# force tbf qdisc to drop traffic

Tags: networking, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc

I have several virtual netspaces on my server connected via the virtual adapters. One of the connections between the netspaces is limited to 10 Mbps:

```
root@core-wkst:/var/log# tc -s qdisc show dev veth7dbb.0.1
qdisc tbf 1: root refcnt 2 rate 10Mbit burst 10000b lat 44.4ms
 Sent 3210158 bytes 43503 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 66b 1p requeues 0
qdisc netem 10: parent 1:1 limit 1000 delay 1.0ms
 Sent 3210068 bytes 43502 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 66b 1p requeues 0
```

This TBF works as intended - I can run iperf and it maxes out at 10Mbps, however, it never dropps packets. So if I run ping between the virtual netspaces when the iperf is running, my delays can reach 2500 ms, but not a single packet will be dropped. Is there a way to force the TBF to have a fixed size queue and drop the packets that does not fit in the queue?